# RegEx.IsMatch() vs. String.ToUpper().Contains() performance

Tags: c#, regex, string

Since there is no case insensitive `string.Contains()` (yet a case insensitive version of `string.Equals()` exists which baffles me, but I digress) in .NET, What is the performance differences between using `RegEx.IsMatch()` vs. using `String.ToUpper().Contains()`?

Example:

```
string testString = "tHiSISaSTRINGwiThInconSISteNTcaPITaLIZATion";

bool containsString = RegEx.IsMatch(testString, "string", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
bool containsStringRegEx = testString.ToUpper().Contains("STRING");
```

I've always heard that `string.ToUpper()` is a very expensive call so I shy away from using it when I want to do `string.Contains()` comparisons, but how does `RegEx.IsMatch()` compare in terms of performance?

Is there a more efficient approach for doing such comparisons?

Comment: Have you tried using [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)?

Comment: The only way to know which one is faster is to run them both and time them.  This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457605/how-to-measure-code-performance-in-net

Comment: What about `testString.IndexOf("string", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0`?

Comment: String.Contains is just a wrapper around `IndexOf(value, StringComparison.Ordinal) >=0`

Comment: IN MOST CASES avoid using ToLower / ToUpper for such things. It's bad practise

Comment: @FabianBigler care to elaborate on that? I can think of a few scenarios where it's perfectly fine to use `ToUpper`/`ToLower` in string comparisons. There can be anomalies when using them based on the culture, it's always safer to use `ToLowerInvariant`/ `ToUpperInvariant`.

Comment: @James I can't, if you are using any function of `String` that has a overload that takes in a `StringComparison` enum, there is NEVER a reason to use ToUpper/ToLower. And to your culture argument, that is what `OrdnalIgnoreCase` is for.

Comment: ToUpper / ToLower may trick you if you support a global world with many languages.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain of course when you have `StringComparison`, however, there are other scenarios where a case insensitive search can't be done and using `ToUpper`/`ToLower` is a good alternative.

Comment: @James Yes, you're right. I was a bit too harsh, so I corrected myself to 'most cases'. But in the very most situations you should be able to solve your problem with StringComparison.

Comment: @MichaelViktorStarberg yep, hence my comment regarding `ToUpperInvariant`/`ToLowerInvariant`.

Comment: @James Yes, but that would not be "situations like these" (the text you originally replied to before it was edited) I can think of situations too, like using a `Switch` statement, but I think that falls firmly in the "different situation" category.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain just to clarify, I am not saying it's ok to use `ToLower`/`ToUpper` if you have the option to use `StringComparison` as clearly `StringComparison` is far more reliable - I was merely responding to the comment as it was originally stated which was along the lines of "*NEVER use `ToLower`/`ToUpper` for string comparison.*"

Comment: On the other hand R# complains everytime you do .ToString() - Enough already! =)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a benchmark

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        string testString = "tHiSISaSTRINGwiThInconSISteNTcaPITaLIZATion";

        sw.Start();
        var re = new Regex("string", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            bool containsString = re.IsMatch(testString);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("RX: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            bool containsStringRegEx = testString.ToUpper().Contains("STRING");
        }


        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Contains: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            bool containsStringRegEx = testString.IndexOf("STRING", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ;
        }


        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("IndexOf: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

Results were

> IndexOf (183ms) > Contains (400ms) > Regex (477ms)

(Updated output times using the compiled Regex)

Comment: Results on my PC: RX: 3032
Contains: 385
IndexOf: 97
 (unoptimized build under mono) (PS. I made the Regex precompiled)

Comment: @Ata - Do you mean its impact on the results? I ran the code with an outside `for` loop over all three tests but the differences were negligible to the results above.

Comment: Wow, I would have never thought that `RegEx` was slower than `ToUpper().Contains()`, and it hadn't even crossed my mind to use `IndexOf() >= 0` to accomplish the task, let alone it being the quickest by far. Thanks! Looks like I will be using `IndexOf()` in the future

Comment: @Saggio - You're welcome. Regex can be slower than string manipulation but it's also a lot more flexible and performs better for more complex parsing so it's a case using the right tool for the job. Personally, for basic string manipulation, I try and avoid regex ([see this post for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457677/how-can-i-remove-none-alphabet-chars-from-a-string))

Answer (score 10):

There is another version using [`String.IndexOf(String,StringComparison)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425.aspx) that might be more efficient than either of the two you suggested:

```
string testString = "tHiSISaSTRINGwiThInconSISteNTcaPITaLIZATion";
bool contained = testString.IndexOf("string", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
```

If you need a culture-sensitive comparison, use `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` instead of `OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect `RegEx.match` to be slow based on personal experience with regular expression parsers in general.  But as many folks have mentioned, profiling it is the best way to find out for sure.  I've had to fix performance issues related to regular expression parsers, `toLower` and `toUpper` have never come back to bite me.