# String format to ignore case in c# windows

Tags: c#, string, format

I need to format the string so that it should ignore case. if the word is "it" then it should consider "It" an "IT" also.How can i achieve that.I have a search function which looks for the word in word document. The below format is to search for the wholeword "it" and not between any word like w"it"nessed. I also want to include the ignore case format. How do i do that

```
   string Pattern = String.Format("<{0}>", text);
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by formatting a string so that it ignores case

Comment: What do you meant by "ignorecase format" ?

Comment: Forget everything you wrote, you want a case insensitive regex search with word boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need "CaseInsensitive Find". `IndexOf` method can do that as an alternative to `Regex`.

```
int index = source.IndexOf(searchKeyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
if(index >= 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found at index " + index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.ToLower()` or `.ToUpper()` on both the pattern and the source when searching, which makes sure that regardless of the initial casing, the cases are identical during the search.

Comment: That sounds really inefficient for searching in a large body of text like a word document. You'd need to transform the entire text for every search.

Comment: @Rotem, you could just save the converted text and search that immediately, so you only need to convert once. It's not optimal for a massive body of text, but definitely the easiest way to get it done if performance is not critical. Should be noted that regexp is not always faster than ToUpper conversion. Here's an example reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579368/regex-ismatch-vs-string-toupper-contains-performance

Comment: The OP never stated how much data there is, so I don't see why this answer is downvoted.

Comment: "I have a search function which looks for the word in word document" - word documents tend to not be very small. I'm not the downvoter btw, the answer is technically correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
String.Compare(first_string, second_string, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ;
```

It'll return -1,0,1 ... so, if you want the same, ignoring case, compare that with 0.

Comment: `String.Compare` is for comparison not search.

Comment: true. question is a bit unclear, but your answers covers the right one then ...